# Poisson process in 2-D

Tags: stochastic-processes, physics, poisson-process

Can we define a 2-D Poisson process such that one of the dimensions is spatial and other in time? Or in other words, if I define a process in space and time such that in any disjoint interval of space and time, the number of occurrences are independent and Poisson distributed with some rate $\lambda$ whose dimension is $1/(space.time)$. Then will the resulting process be a Poisson process? Is there any good literature available where this kind of applications are found?

Comment: Do you move along some vector or what? What is an "occurrence" in this setting?

Comment: Yes you can say so . To generalize, let’s say I want to model the number of earthquakes in a given 2D location for any interval of time . then if for any disjoint location and interval of time the number of earthquake occurrences is independent and Poison distributed with some mean value function which depends on the x y interval and the time interval. then can I claim the entire process to be poison process? note that I am not talking of a stationary process , it can as well be non stationary poison process.